# Differentiating between queries that have similar words in them

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm attempting to use awk to pull the queries: **COMPLETED**, **ASSIGNED**, **UNASSIGNED**, **REVIEWED**, **REVIEW ASSIGNED**, and **ERROR** from each line in a log file. The end result looks something close to:

```
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
UNASSIGNED
REVIEWED
ERROR
...
```

However, I am getting some problems with the words/phrases mixing up with each other, specifically with **REVIEW ASSIGNED**. It's taking any of my statements that should be **REVIEW ASSIGNED** and just making them **ASSIGNED**. My awk statement is:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^(REVIEWED|COMPLETED|REVIEW ASSIGNED|ASSIGNED|UNASSIGNED|ERROR)$/){print $i}}}' myFile
```

I've attempted to look it up, but I'm unfamiliar with awk and haven't found anything specifically on how to deal with expressions that contain multiple words considering that it is separated on white-space.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are some lines not being matched? Is the output not the format you want? Can you show us sample input and the output you want to get from that input?

Comment: Sure, I edited the post a bit. REVIEW ASSIGNED is being turned into ASSIGNED, and I'm having difficulty preserving the integrity of the former statement due to the white-space in between it.

Comment: Ah. I see. Answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping and matching field-by-field but whitespace splits fields in awk (by default) so no field in the line is going to ever be `REVIEW ASSIGNED`.

So instead of matching `REVIEW ASSIGNED` like you wanted that line matches the `ASSIGNED` test instead.

Stop looping fields and just use something like this:

```
awk 'match($0, /(REVIEWED|COMPLETED|REVIEW ASSIGNED|ASSIGNED|UNASSIGNED|ERROR)/, a) {print a[0]}' myFile
```

Ed Morton points out that this usage of `match` is gawk specific (because it adds support for the third array argument to `match`). A version that doesn't use that feature would look like this

```
awk 'match($0, /(REVIEWED|COMPLETED|REVIEW ASSIGNED|ASSIGNED|UNASSIGNED|ERROR)/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}' myFile
```

Aside:

I thought Ed Morton was pointing out that this regexp will never match `UNASSIGNED` correctly as `ASSIGNED` will always match first however it would appear awk's regexp engine doesn't have that issue. For an engine that did, however, inverting the order would likely fix that problem.

```
awk 'match($0, /(REVIEWED|COMPLETED|REVIEW ASSIGNED|UNASSIGNED|ASSIGNED|ERROR)/, a) {print a[0]}' myFile
```

Comment: Note that `ASSIGNED` is unnecessarily redundant, as it is contained in both `REVIEW ASSIGNED` and `UNASSIGNED`.

Comment: Without the pattern anchors that is true. If I knew the input file format more I'd probably have attempted to include appropriate anchors which might have ended up making it not as entirely redundant. There's also something to be said (depending on circumstance) for the self-documenting nature of including the full set of valid options (redundant or not).

Comment: Can the matching string only appear once per line? Does the order of the regexp terms matter (e.g. if `UNASSIGNED` exists on a line will it ever be found or will the `ASSIGNED` match first)? You should mention this is gawk-specific due to the 3rd arg for match().

Comment: @EdMorton Good point about `ASSIGNED` breaking `UNASSIGNED` matching. `UNASSIGNED` shouldn't ever match this way. The order would need to be inverted for that to work. I wasn't aware that was gawk specific. I'll add an answer with `substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)` assuming that's portable?

Comment: Actually, UNASSIGNED will match because awk uses left-most **longest** matching. Just giving you something to think about :-). Yeah, the substr() solution would be portable. Not sure if there can only be one match per line though - OP hasn't shared that tidbit with us yet.

Comment: I don't think I want to think about why `UNASSIGNED` matches here too much right now but thanks anyway. =)

Comment: Can't say I blame you. I actually wondered about it myself first and then realized it would so I thought I'd share the pain :-). It matches for the same reason that `echo 'xxx' | awk 'match($0, /x+/, a) {print a[0]}` will print all 3 xs and not just one - awk always looks for the left-most **longest** match to an RE.